# "Main Not Found" starting Apache Geronimo

Tags: apache, azure, amazon-ec2, geronimo

I am attempting to start Apache Geronimo using the command:
./bin/geronimo run

When I do this, it spins for a minute, issues the message "Main not found" and exits.

This article suggests that it is a system resource issue:

http://apache-geronimo.328035.n3.nabble.com/jira-Created-GERONIMO-5551-Failing-to-start-the-server-with-the-error-quot-Main-not-found-quot-td1324013.html

I have tried it on both an Amazon EC2 box (running Linux), and an Azure A1 box (running Windows Server), and I have tried the "Full Profile Release" and "Web Profile Release" of Geronimo, all with no change.

I'm at a complete loss as to what I could try.  I am led to believe that the EC2 box, at the very least, should have the muscle to run Geronimo.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Version 3 of Apache Geronimo is designed to run on JRE 1.7 instead of JRE 1.8. As stated in the other answers, the issue was caused by Geronimo being run on JRE 1.7 instead of 1.8.

You are not limited to JRE 1.7 and earlier in order to run Geronimo though. Therefore, all you have to do is to rename or copy the property `jre-1.7` in the file `etc/config.properties` in your installation to `jre-1.8`. Afterwards, you should be able to run Geronimo without an error.

This has a huge benefit, since now you will be able to run programs on Geronimo that use Java 8 features.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the issue is that I had the wrong version of the JDK installed.  I had installed the most recent version (8), but Geronimo apparently won't work with that.  When I instead installed version 6, everything worked fine.

Comment: You actually *can* use Geronimo 3 with Java 8. Therefore, you have to rename or copy the property `jre-1.7` in the file `etc/config.properties` to `jre-1.8`.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error with Java 8.  I tried the latest version of Java SE 7 and that resolved the problem.  So I wouldn't use Java 6, since it is and has been out of support for awhile now (read: security issue).